# Simple Projectile. Straight up

Tags: python, python-2.7, projectile

I am simply trying to figure out the position based with a varying t and a vaying v_0.

What is wrong with this short program here?

```
#Position from Simple Equation
t = input('Time (in seconds)')
g = 9.81
v_0 = input('initial velocity')

s=-0.5*g*t^2 + v_0*t

print s
```

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: What makes you think that there is something wrong with it? Does it error out or else? Or you just want somebody else to make you homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` operator in `t^2` is a [bit-wise XOR operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

```
>>> 3 ^ 3
0
```

If you intended [the power operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator), use `**` instead.

```
>>> 3 ** 3
27
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7, not 3.0

Comment: Ahhh That was my problem all along. Thanks a bunch bro. Would already accept your answer but they are making me wait 6 minutes.